# Does this connector exist and if so what is the correct name?

Tags: pcb-design, connector, identification

Please see picture.

- 2.54mm pin pitch.
- 8 pins, 8 'ways'.

So, "1x8" I think is the right way to state it?

[image: representation of connector layout]

I am trying to find a connector / header / whatever-name-is-correct to change direction 90 degrees in the vertical direction rather than on the board-plane direction like is commonly seen and easily found by searching for 90 deg headers.

I have searched using many search terms including 'upstand' 'vertical' '90 deg' 'board to board' and more that seemed like 'maybes'. Scrolling through many hundreds of pictures with no luck, so am desperate now and posting here.

I have seen board to board connectors like what I want in older electronics (a TV set, an ancient copier) though the ones I saw did not have a plastic housing at the pin end, only at the 'ways' end, and those were both 16 or more pins not 8 like I need.

Please tell me the correct name for such a connector, if they exist?

Comment: You would need terms like "right-angled" connector and "1 position" or "1 column" and "octal row" or "8 rows". However, this connector may also be defined as right-angled 8 positions... They may be listed as "backplane connector"

Comment: With many columns they actually exist: https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=A121106-ND
But I've never seen a single-column one. I'd design a small PCB for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my almost 40 years of tearing apart electronics, I have only seen what you are specifically asking for once or twice in the SIP form-factor, and each time it was a custom OEM part that wasn't available on the open market.

Although they are rarely seen these days, 90 degree DIP sockets were at one time popular back when discreet non-multiplexed LED display modules were common.  They still appear to be available, at least to some limited degree:

---

[image: LED Display Socket]

So, I guess the proper term would be "8 pin 90 degree vertical SIP socket", but like I said, such a thing does not exist on the open market as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ah-HA!  Have gone to E-Tec website and have that PDF printed to bring to my local parts place. (Did not seem to see a way to order direct from that website) Also found these at my local online source - but at 17 bucks each... So need to find better source, and cut in half vertically. Any chance you can add what the proper name for a "single" version would be? Then I can mark as the answer.

Comment: Um... I've puzzled out that SIP is single and DIP is double, so if "SIP" is the way to designate "all pins in line with each other" and "8-way" designates how many holes and pins, and 'vertical' is how to designate the orientation of pins vs. ways... then clarify with complete term in the answer?

Comment: @111936 - OK, I edited the answer to include a full designation.  It's probably not practical to manufacture what you are looking for, since a single row of pins would not be mechanically stable, and practically no one would want to purchase them in the first place.  As you can see already, so few people even want to purchase a DIP version that they are going to be extremely expensive.  E-Tec is a manufacturer, and does not sell directly, but there is a link at the top of their website with a list of international distributors.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find that you have to make that,

I have often seen flat cable used and it is usually folded neatly to achieve the direction change and limit the space needed.

So, as per my first line above, ie "making that", you could get two plastic headers, remove the pins then bend wires for each position and push them into place. A small vise may help in keeping the wires under control.

Comment: Cannot use ribbon because then all 8 wires are as long as the longest - and I need to keep the distance on the "innermost" pins as short as is possible. Have a capacitor that needs to be very close to the second pin from the 'corner'. So yeah, could do but can't do. May have to solder up my own from the pictured parts in my 'approximation' picture, but wanted to buy them if i could because thats a lot of time to make four of them..

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen one of those.

I am afraid you have to make your own.

1/ You could try to get a very long wire (e.g. wire wrap) version and bend the wires.

2/ Bend the pins of one of your shown connectors and solder them to a 8-pin header.

Answer (score -1):

Well that part is a DIP connector but is known as FEMALE PIN HEADER, so you need a 90 Degree Female Pin Header. You can find it normaly as 40 pin header then you can cut it to the required size.

[image]

There are also 90 degree male Pin Header to complete your designs.

[image]

You can buy this part on any spare parts electronic store like Radio Shack if still exist, but on ebay or Ali express are easy to find it.

Comment: These are not what I tried to describe. Apologies for lack of clarity. I'm seeking that all 8 pins and all 8 ways are on the same plane - 90 degrees ON a plane... The pictured ones have pins at 90 degrees to the ways, so pins and ways are on different planes.

Comment: Those don’t seem to match the orientation the OP is looking for...

Comment: It certainly is not DIP, as it means dual in-line package, it is rather octal-in-line. Compensated for the incorrect +1 vote

Comment: @111936 This shows the orientation of 90 degree instead normal pin head, THIS IS A Single Line DIP connector since is to insert DIP components, if the user need two lines then is called Dual DIP, for IC's is called DIP IC Socket. I Said that this comes on 40 pin strips but can be trimmed, also there are for 2X1,3X1, 4X1, ... 8X1 and so on. There are only two options STRAIGHT (normal) and 90°.  SolarMike recommended to use a Ribbon Strip, this kind of wires are used in OLD TV's, So you can have one from an OLD BUS CABLE, the problem will be the peeling. I used this at Ford Electronics on 1992.